# Which compiler, if any has a bug in parameter pack expansion?

Tags: c++, c++14, language-lawyer, variadic-templates

When experimenting with convenient ways to access tuples as containers, I wrote a test program.

on clang (3.9.1, and apple clang) it compiles as expected, producing the expected output:

```
1.1
foo
2
```

on gcc (5.4, 6.3), it fails to compile:

```
<source>: In lambda function:
<source>:14:61: error: parameter packs not expanded with '...':
             +[](F& f, Tuple& tuple) { f(std::get<Is>(tuple)); }...
                                                             ^
<source>:14:61: note:         'Is'
<source>: In function 'decltype(auto) notstd::make_callers_impl(std::index_sequence<Is ...>)':
<source>:14:64: error: expansion pattern '+<lambda>' contains no argument packs
             +[](F& f, Tuple& tuple) { f(std::get<Is>(tuple)); }...
                                                                ^~~
Compiler exited with result code 1
```

Question: who is right? Can it be fixed?

Program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <tuple>

namespace notstd {

    template<class F, class Tuple, std::size_t...Is>
    auto make_callers_impl(std::index_sequence<Is...>) -> decltype(auto)
    {
        static std::array<void (*) (F&, Tuple&), sizeof...(Is)> x =
        {
            +[](F& f, Tuple& tuple) { f(std::get<Is>(tuple)); }...
        };
        return x;
    };

    template<class F, class Tuple>
    auto make_callers() -> decltype(auto)
    {
        return make_callers_impl<F, Tuple>(std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size<std::decay_t<Tuple>>::value>());
    };

    template<class Tuple, std::size_t N = std::tuple_size<std::decay_t<Tuple>>::value >
    struct tuple_iterator {
        static constexpr auto size = N;

        constexpr tuple_iterator(Tuple& tuple, std::size_t i = 0) : tuple(tuple), i(i) {}

        template<class F>
        void with(F&& f) const {
            static const auto& callers = make_callers<F, Tuple>();
            callers[i](f, tuple);
        }

        constexpr bool operator!=(tuple_iterator const& r) const {
            return i != r.i;
        }

        constexpr auto operator++() -> tuple_iterator& {
            ++i;
            return *this;
        }


        Tuple& tuple;
        std::size_t i;
    };

    template<class Tuple>
    auto begin(Tuple&& tuple)
    {
        return tuple_iterator<Tuple>(std::forward<Tuple>(tuple));
    }

    template<class Tuple>
    auto end(Tuple&& tuple)
    {
        using tuple_type = std::decay_t<Tuple>;
        static constexpr auto size = std::tuple_size<tuple_type>::value;
        return tuple_iterator<Tuple>(std::forward<Tuple>(tuple), size);
    }

}

template<class T> void emit(const T&);

int main() {
    auto a = std::make_tuple(1.1, "foo", 2);
    auto i = notstd::begin(a);
    while(i != notstd::end(a))
    {
        i.with([](auto&& val) { std::cout << val << std::endl; });
        ++i;
    }
}
```

Comment: I suggest you to add the tag `language-lawyer` to this question, since it's about compiler conformance to the standard

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot so done. thank you.

Comment: Well I'd guess that Clang is right because the code compiles and works as expected and since gcc is throwing compiler errors it must not have been implemented or fixed in the current version.

Comment: Slightly of topic, but you don't need to create the static callers. Maybe you did this to expose the bug, but you could have just called​ f inside the with method.

Comment: @Walther I'm getting old and my brain works better in single steps. I did notice that removing `static const` and replacing with `constexpr` increases efficiency while still maintaining clarity (for me). In fact, clang is epic at inlining constexpr jump tables. gcc less so.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is [gcc bug 47226](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=47226). gcc simply does not allow producing a pack expansions of lambdas like that. The bug is still present in 7.0.

---

In this case, you don't really need the lambda and can just create a function template:

```
template <size_t I, class F, class Tuple>
void lambda(F& f, Tuple& tuple) {
    f(std::get<I>(tuple));
}

static std::array<void (*) (F&, Tuple&), sizeof...(Is)> x = 
{
    lambda<Is,F,Tuple>...
};
```

Answer (score 4):

clang is right.

Parameter packs must be expanded, but gcc seems to think that unexpanded parameter packs at the end of a statement are errors.  This is understandable, but lambdas permit statements to be just a small part of other statements.  There is no requirement that parameter packs be expanded before the end of every statement they are in.

Here is an inline workaround:

```
template<std::size_t I>
using index_t=std::integral_constant<std::size_t, I>
template<std::size_t I>
constexpr index_t<I> index{};
```

then inside the function:

```
  auto lamb = [](auto I){
    using I_t=decltype(I);
    return [](F& f, Tuple& tuple) { f(std::get<I_t::value>(tuple)); };
  };
  static std::array<void (*) (F&, Tuple&), sizeof...(Is)> x =
  {
    +(lamb(index_k<Is>))...
  };
```

which moves the lambda body outside of the `...`.  We pass the constant by value.  You can even pass types that way.

Another pattern is:

```
template<std::size_t...Is>
auto index_over(std::index_sequence<Is...>){
  return [](auto&&f)->decltype(auto){
    return decltype(f)(f)( index_k<Is>... );
  };
}
template<std::size_t N>
auto index_upto(index_t<N>={}){
  return index_over(std::make_index_sequence<N>{});
}
template<class F>
auto array_maker(F f){
  return [f=std::move(f)](auto...Is)->std::array<decltype(f(index_k<0>),sizeof...(Is)>{
    return {{f(Is...}};
  };
}
```

this lets you dodge your problem entirely, and kills impl:

```
template<class F, class Tuple>
auto make_callers() -> decltype(auto)
{
  auto size=index_k<std::tuple_size<std::decay_t<Tuple>>{}>;
  auto indexer=index_upto(size);
  auto make_array=array_maker([](auto I){
    return +[](F& f, Tuple& tuple) { f(std::get<decltype(I)::value>(tuple)); };
  });
  return indexer(make_array);
}
```

which admittedly is rather over lambdad.